# python help() function shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, python

What are shortcuts of Python `help()` function used in Python interpreter?

I'm interested for help content that doesn't fit to window and shows "-- More --" at the bottom. I found `q` quits `help()`. What is a shortcut to show the whole article w/o pressing `Enter` many times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my (Linux) machine help seems to be using "less". Press "h" when in help to see a complete list of shortcuts/commands. I'm not sure if this will work on Windows though.

Answer (score 3):

The `help()` function in Python interactive interpreter is based on the `pydoc` module. There's a function called `getpager()` in this module that decides what to use to display the help depending on various factors.

In most cases it will use the `less` command on Linux and `more` on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

One shortcut is the <kbd>space bar</kbd> - it displays the next page of the help text (instead of the next line like <kbd>Enter</kbd>).